# Display data information directly from MS Access Database to several textboxes

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, textbox

I'm using a listview as trigger to put my data to the textboxes. But I want to display the Firstname, lastname and middle initial from my access database directly to the textboxes. My code in displaying my data to textboxes.

The outcome is this [image]
And my code is this

```
If Not ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        txtqrCode.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).Text
        cbCategory.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(1).Text
        Dim str As String = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(2).Text
        Dim splitStr As String() = str.Split(","c)
        txtLastName.Text = splitStr(0).Trim()
        txtFirstName.Text = splitStr(1).Trim()
        txtMiddleInitial.Text = splitStr(2).Trim()
        cbGender.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(3).Text
        txtAddress.Text = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(4).Text
    End If
```

And Connecting my access database to my listview.

```
Private Sub ApplicationDesignForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Connection()
    sql = "Select * From App"
    rs.Open(sql, Conn)
    While Not rs.EOF
            Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(rs.Fields("QRCode").Value)
            item.SubItems.Add(rs("Category").Value)
            item.SubItems.Add(rs("LastName").Value & ", " & rs("FirstName").Value & ", " & rs("MI").Value)
            item.SubItems.Add(rs("Gender").Value)
            item.SubItems.Add(rs("Address").Value)
            ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
            rs.MoveNext()
    End While
```

End Sub

Is there some other solution? And what is the code? Please need some help.

Comment: TextBoxes can show only one item at time, while you read the access data you should choose what record to show. What is wrong in adding them to the ListView and then choose the one to show from there?

Comment: I want to add them by using the textbox of QRCode as my trigger, so that I will not using the code inside my list. Because In some cases that there are a lot of string in one column then my code is much more. I want a new one with lesser of code but the same functions as what my listview is.